# PHP output text on image character encoding error

Tags: php, image-processing, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
imagestring( $my_img, 4, $colC, $row1, money_format('%(#5n', $rates[0][0]), $text_colour );

...
...
...

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_colour );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_colour );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
```

Everything works fine, however I have a strange error...

The currency symbol looks wrong. Instead of showing a **£** sign, it shows an **A** with a caret on top and what looks like the bottom half of a pound sign.

So I tried to remove the .UTF-8 and the **A** with a caret disappears but it still only shows the bottom half of the pound sign.

What I want, is simply a **£** sign. Can anybody help please???

[image: PHP Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php), `imagestring` only supports Latin2 in the default font, which cannot encode `£`. Even if it could encode `£`, you should have converted your UTF-8 to Latin2 before passing it.

Use [`imageTtfText`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) which supports UTF-8. You need to point it to a working TrueType font file in the 7th argument.